# R: Adding '+' in front of 'positive' characters

Tags: r

I'm trying to add a '+' symbol to show a percent increase in numbers that were made into characters in order to add a % sign in front of all of them. Here is some sample data:

```
###Create Data
First.Name <- c("Sharon", "Megan", "Kevin")
ProjManagment <- c(5, 7,3)
ClientManagment <- c(3,6,2)
StatProgram <- c(2,3,7)
jobForm = data.frame(First.Name, ProjManagment, ClientManagment, StatProgram)
```

And the code to make them into percentages:

```
as.character(jobForm[2:4])
jobForm[2:4] <- lapply(jobForm[2:4], function(x) paste(x, "%"))
```

I have tried to do this:

```
jobForm[32:39] <- lapply(jobForm[32:39]) function(x) if(strsplit(x[0] != "-")) {paste("+", x)}
```

and this from a previously posted question:

```
jobForm[32:39] <- lapply(jobForm[32:39], function(x, ...)
{
  if (x[1] != "-")
  {
    sprintf(
      fmt = "+ %s",
      format(x, ...)
    )
  }
  else
  {
    x
  }
})
```

But none have worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
jobForm[2:4] <- lapply(jobForm[2:4], function(x) {
  x.c <- paste0(ifelse(x >= 0, "+", ""), x, "%")
})
```

Do this before you convert things to a character - the conversion is automatic.  You can replace `paste0` with `paste` if you want spaces between the different elements.  (If you just want a space after the number, add that before the % sign.

Answer (score 15):

No need for an `if`/`else` condition here. You can simply use `sprintf` with the format specifiers `"%+d"` or `%+f`; e.g.

```
jobForm[2:4] <- lapply(jobForm[2:4], function(x) sprintf("%+3d %%", x))
#  First.Name ProjManagment ClientManagment StatProgram
#1     Sharon          +5 %            +3 %        +2 %
#2      Megan          +7 %            +6 %        +3 %
#3      Kevin          +3 %            +2 %        +7 %
```

Explanation: Let's break down the format specifier `"%+3d"`: The `+` flag adds a leading plus, `3` specifies three integer digits, and `d` (`f`) specifies an integer (float). We escape the percentage sign inside `sprintf` by doubling it.

A minimal example to further demonstrate

```
x <- c(0.0, -3.2, 4.2)
sprintf("%+3d %%", x)
#[1] " +0 %" " -3 %" " +4 %"

sprintf("%+3.1f %%", x)
#[1] "+0.0 %" "-3.2 %" "+4.2 %"
```

Comment: Hi Maurits! Thanks for your suggestion. I created the data as a small example of what I need to add + to. The actual data is very long with 100s of observations. Is there another way I could apply sprintf to this kind of dataset, without having to go through everything and check all negative numbers? Thank you

Comment: @skk Using `ifelse` or `if`/`else` will be a slower than using `sprintf`, and there is really no point in using such a construct here. The whole point of using `%+d` is that you *don't* have to check for positive/negative numbers; it *automatically* places a `"+"` in front of positive numbers, while negative numbers will keep their `"-"` signs (as usual).